# question about integration of symmetrical graph to find area

Tags: integration, area

[image]

let's say, we have an symmetrical curve such as $x=\sqrt{y}$

If we integrate from 4 to 0, wouldn't it cancel out with the area on the other side of the axis?

When integration is performed from 4 to 0, where exactly is the area we are getting?

Comment: so when we integrate 4 to 0, we are getting the entire shaded region?

Comment: The graph of $x = \sqrt y$ is only the right half of the parabola $y = x^2$.

Comment: The dependent variable in this graph is $y$ so this is a function, ${\rm{f(x) = }}{{\rm{x}}^2}$

Comment: @Kakayou You have 2 unchallenged answers. I hope you find them useful. Can you close this question by accepting an answer - this is customary on the website. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the integral of the function $f(x) = \sqrt x $ over the interval $0 \le x \le 4$ yields the area$$ \int\limits_0^4 {{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}} dx=\left[ {\frac{2}{3}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}} \right]_0^4$$
However, for a function $f(x) =  \pm \sqrt x $ the integral over this interval is given by  $$ + \int\limits_0^4 {{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}} dx - \int\limits_0^4 {{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}} dx = 0$$.

The second integral is negative only by virtue that the height of $f$ takes negative values as well as positive. In contrast to the height of the function, the area enclosed by any function can never be negative by definition of area.

It is therefore not sufficient to compute integrals when considering areas. It is also necessary to consider the position of the function with respect to the $y-axis$.

In this example the function is symmetrical about the $x-axis$ so it is convenient to compute the required area as $$ 2 \int\limits_0^4 {{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}} dx =2\left[ {\frac{2}{3}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}} \right]_0^4$$

Answer (score 0):

Area is an unsigned scalar. Area = $ \int _ {0} ^ {4} y  \,dx $  or $ \int _ {4} ^ {0} y  \,dx $  i.e., x- limits taken between  $ x=0 , x=-2 $ or $x=-2 , x =0 $ is quite the same. Like between cuts in a pie of cake its area or weight is same whether  you take a cut first at the left or at the right.